# Is there a way to combine INSERT INTO SELECT with the normal VALUES command in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables:

`T_Computer` => with `Automatic`, `ComputerID` and `Computername`

`T_MissingUpdates` => with `ComputerID`, `Update` and `UpdateKB`.

I insert the `Computername`, `Update` and `UpdateKB` with a c# script which does a sql command.

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "insert into T_Computer (computername) values ('" + Computername + "')";
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcmd.CommandText = "insert into T_MissingUpdates (UpdateName, UpdateKB) values ('" + updatename + "', '" + UpdateKB + "') "; sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What i need is to use the same ComputerID from T_Computer for The T_MissingUpdates ComputerID.
I barely ever used sql so i dont really know how to do this.

Comment: why are you inserting in T_Computer just the `computername`?

Comment: Do a `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('T_Computer')` after first query and use the result in the second insert query.

Comment: Your statement is a recipe for SQL Injection, you should look into properly parameterising your query.

Comment: Don't do what you're doing; throw all that code away. Take a quick tutorial on using EF; it will make your life so much simpler, like `var c new Computer(...); context.Computers.Add(c); c.MissingUpdates.Add(new MissingUpdate(...)); context.SaveChanges();` - that's it: EF handles all the SQL, the parameters, the new computer's ID, the record relationships.. It'll take you half a day of frustration to bang your code into something that looks right and does the same amount of work as what EF did there in 4 lines/30 seconds

Comment: @SalmanA No, always use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or an `OUTPUT` clause

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: Using EF is very much a matter of opinion - it can equally make your DBA's life a misery and cause you any number of performance issues depending on what you throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following statements:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "insert into T_Computer (computername) values ('" + Computername + "')";
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcmd.CommandText = "insert into T_MissingUpdates (UpdateName, UpdateKB, computerID) values ('" + updatename + "', '" + UpdateKB + "', select t_computer.computerID from t_computer where t_computer.computername = '" + Computername + "')";
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As long as the value of T_Computer.computername is unique